# Hessian and gradient in a matrix

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

There is following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\nabla^2g(x) & \nabla g(x)\\\ \nabla g(x)^{T} & 1\end{pmatrix} \ge 0$$

the "$\ge$" is general inequality (not element-wise), meaning the matrix is *positive-semi definite*.  The $g(x)$ is convex and $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The goal is to prove, the $h(x) = -exp(-g(x))$ is convex.

---

QUESTION:

What information does the positive semi-definite matrix gives about the convexity of $f(x)$ ? I dont understand what information is given about $\nabla^2g(x)$ and $\nabla g(x)$ by stating the matrix is positive semi-definite.

Does it imply $\nabla^2g(x) \ge \nabla g(x)\nabla g(x)^T$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the case where $n=1$. You are given that
$$\begin{pmatrix}g''(x) & g'(x)\\\ g'(x) & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

is positive semi-definite. This is true if and only if the all principal minors are non-negative. Thus we can conclude that $$g''(x)\geq [g'(x)]^2.$$

(Also $g''(x)\geq 0$, but we already knew that because we are told that $g$ is convex).

The first derivative of $h$ is
$$h'(x)=\exp(-g(x))g'(x)$$

The second derivative of $h$ is
$$\begin{align}h''(x)&=\exp(-g(x))g'(x)\\&=-\exp(-g(x))[g'(x)]^2+\exp(-g(x))g''(x)\\ &=\exp(-g(x))(g''(x)-[g'(x)]^2)\end{align}$$

Since the first term in the product is positive, and we know the term in brackets is non-negative, we can conclude that $h''(x)\geq 0$ and so $h$ is convex.

Now "all" you need to do is rewrite that for the general case.